# Computing eigenvectors from the QR algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I've seen a few other posts  on this topic but none have full answers.

I'm trying to implement some eigen-decomposition algorithms. I've managed to get the Explicit QR algorithm and the Implicit (Francis) algorithm to compute the eigenvalues. My question however relates to computing the eigenvectors.

My core question is:

Do I need to use the [Inverse Iteration Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration) to get the eigenvectors after completing the QR algorithm?

I understand additionally that I'll need to use the transformation matrices from my QR algorithm (balancing, the hessenberg reduction and the QR decomposition). But I'm more interested right now in whether there is some way to get the eigenvectors from the QR algorithm itself (as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Iterative_algorithms) implies there is).

Comment: For reference I've been using the following sources:

1. http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter3.pdf - Implementation of Hessenberg and implicit QR algorithm.
2. [On Matrix Balancing and EigenVector Computation](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.5766v1.pdf) - James, Langou and Lowery.

Comment: If the matrix is normal, then the columns of the $Q$ matrix are precisely the eigenvectors.

Comment: @ChristianClason This covers symmetric matrices. Is there a way to recover the eigenvectors for general matrices?

Comment: Well, normal matrices, which is more general than symmetric. General (non-normal) matrices need not have eigenvectors (in the sense of unique vectors up to scalar multiples).

Comment: Sure I understand that - and in my particular application I'm only working with reals. But assuming even that my matrix has distinct, real, eigenvectors - can I retrieve these from the QR algorithm?

Comment: If your matrix has distinct real eigenvectors, they *will* be the columns of the $Q$ matrix. (And the $R$ matrix will be diagonal.) This is the case if and only if the matrix is normal.

Comment: Ah ok. And if the matrix has real eigenvectors which are not necessarily distinct. Can these still be recovered from the Q matrix?

Comment: Then sets of columns of $Q$ will form a basis of the corresponding eigenspace (or invariant subspace). Given a matrix $A$, the QR algorithm converges to the real Schur factorization $A = QRQ^*$, i.e., $AQ = QR$.